# What tier are PF Druids and Clerics when using D&D 3.5e's Spontaneous Divine Casters variant class rules?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, druid, balance

My friend told me that he disallows playing the standard Druid, Cleric and Wizard, because they, [being T1 classes](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=11990.0), can prepare new spells every day and no problem will take more than 24 hours to get the needed tool if they don't have one yet, especially at later levels — it's just a matter of preparing the right spells.

Instead of the Wizard, he suggests people to play the Sorcerer, and instead of the Druid and Cleric, to use the [D&D 3.5e Spontaneous Divine Casters variant class rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/spontaneousDivineCasters.htm) with the Pathfinder Druid and Cleric, which he says are fully compatible with these variant rules.

**What tier are the Druid and Cleric when using the ported variant spellcasting?**

Comment: Uh, you have a question tagged Pathfinder but link to a 3.5 variant. I assume you mean the Pathfinder version of these classes, but with the spells known/per-day of the spontaneous variant there?

Comment: Are you asking what tier the spontaneous casters are, or are you asking whether substituting spontaneous casting for prepared in druid & cleric helps with the "problem" of tiers?

Comment: I would like to know those two things as well. Aside from being unsure what classes you're asking about due to the link confusion, it also looks like there *might* be two questions here, but possibly it's one question expressed two ways, in which latter case it would be useful to edit it to be more clearly one question to prevent answers from interpreting it wrongly as two different questions.

Comment: *At worst* this is two **deeply** related questions, that seem far more convenient to answer together than separately.

Comment: @KRyan I don't know, a friend linked me to this. If Pathfinder has different rules for Spontaneous Divine Casters, I would gladly see them, but the question still persists. I edited the question so there is only one left now.

Comment: @KRyan Very much agreed! I am more concerned for procedural reasons though, in that answers could cherry-pick one or the other to focus on and thus treat them as separate questions, leading to a preventable mess. My understanding is that the second question is “is my friend right about their tiers, and therefore about the efficacy of this fix?”, but an answer could interpret it otherwise. And if that's correct, it's just a redundant restatement, which isn't useful if it muddies instead of clarifies. (And it's been removed anyway.)

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Please confirm with your friend which classes answers are supposed to be written about. If he does intend to use the 3.5e variant rule with Pathfinder, we need that to be explicit. Otherwise the mismatch and lack of explanation for the mismatch will be confusing readers for years to come, and it will sooner or later be closed as unclear for that reason, whether it's reopened now or not.

Comment: For a Pathfinder "spontaneous cleric", check out the Oracle: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/oracle.html

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I checked the chat log, he told me to google for "Spontaneous Divine Casters", not "Oracle" or something like that.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Well, oracle **is** a spontaneous divine spellcaster, that uses the cleric list and can therefore be thought of as being to the cleric as sorcerer is to the wizard. I don’t *think* there are any spontaneous spellcasting classes using the druid’s list, though. (Ultimately, whatever he meant, it doesn’t *really* change the answer to the question, though.)

Comment: @KRyan He explicitely confirmed that he meant to port the 3.5 rules, saying that they are almost fully compatible with Pathfinder.

Comment: @KRyan Just forgot about it. Gonna go through the list of my questions to check if I forgot to do it somewhere else too. BTW, your answer was upvoted. Thank you for it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tier 2.

The quintessential tier 1-2 divide is sorcerer and wizard. They both have access to the same (fantastically powerful) spell list, but the wizard can choose exactly the spells he needs every day, while the sorcerer is locked into the (still fantastically powerful) spells he’s chosen to learn. One glib way to put the distinction is “a tier 2 can do anything; a tier 1 can do *everything.*”

It’s difficult to make claims about the relative power of classes within a tier (and, for that matter, tiers are not strictly about power to begin with), but (with the nerfs to wild shape since 3.5), druid is generally regarded as the worst of the tier-1 classes (worst of the best is still pretty good, obviously). Made spontaneous, the druid would thus drop to the bottom of the tier-2 classes, most likely. On the other hand, half-elf sorcerers, between their eligibility to take the incredible human favored class bonus (“+1 spell known; must be of a level 1 less than max”) and the *paragon surge* spell, are very-nearly tier 1, arguably competitive with the prepared-spellcasting druid.